# jQuery: Count number of list elements?

Tags: jquery, html

I've got a list that is generated from some server side code, before adding extra stuff to it with jQuery I need to figure out how many items are already in it.

```
<ul id="mylist">
    <li>Element 1</li>
    <li>Element 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 228, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#mylist li").length
```

Just curious: why do you need to know the size?  Can't you just use:

```
$("#mylist").append("<li>New list item</li>");
```

?

Comment: I'm using appending to add the new ones, but I've got a limit on the number of items that can be in the list, in this state the user can still add upto a max of 4 items, but 2 might have come from the previous state. :)

Comment: Note that the jQyery docs recommend using `.length` over `.size()` to avoid the overhead of a function call. http://api.jquery.com/size/

Comment: [size() was deprecated in jquery 1.8](http://api.jquery.com/size/) and it says to use [length()](http://api.jquery.com/length/) now.

Comment: @gloomy.penguin Note that `.length` is not a function.

Comment: I need the <li> count in order to recalculate the element width on the fly.

Answer (score 52):

```
var listItems = $("#myList").children();

var count = listItems.length;
```

Of course you can condense this with

```
var count = $("#myList").children().length;
```

For more help with jQuery, http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page is a good place to start.

Comment: just to be safe, do $("#myList").children("li").length; If you ever add other items inside the list for any reason, you won't forget about this small line of code.

Answer (score 10):

You have the same result when calling .size() method or .length property   but the .length property is preferred because it doesn't have the overhead of a function call.
So the best way:

```
$("#mylist li").length
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this should do it:

```
var ct = $('#mylist').children().size();
```

Answer (score 4):

and of course the following:

```
var count = $("#myList").children().length;
```

can be condensed down to:  (by removing the 'var' which is not necessary to set a variable)

```
count = $("#myList").children().length;
```

---

however this is cleaner:

```
count = $("#mylist li").size();
```

Comment: Isn't this method also counting li-tags within child ul-elements of the top ul?

Comment: Saying "'var' is not necessary to set a variable" is oversimplifying. If you don't use 'var', all your varibles will end up global. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

try

```
$("#mylist").children().length
```

Answer (score 1):

Count number of list elements

```
alert($("#mylist > li").length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to count number of list elements:

```js
var num = $("#mylist").find("li").length;
console.log(num);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="mylist">
  <li>Element 1</li>
  <li>Element 2</li>
  <li>Element 3</li>
  <li>Element 4</li>
  <li>Element 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    alert($("li").length);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Count the number of specific elements</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li>List - 1</li>
  <li>List - 2</li>
  <li>List - 3</li>
</ul>
  <button>Display the number of li elements</button>
</body>
</html>
```