# Count all first list items in ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, count, html-lists

I was wondering how to count all the list items inside a div.

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Information</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">History</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Present</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Future</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Tutorials</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">HTML/CSS</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Javascript</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Jquery</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">PHP</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Structure</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How do I count all the list elements inside `ul class=menu`? And not the list items who are in a deeper UL.

What I mean is how to count Home, Contact, Information, Tutorials, Structure, and not the list elements who are inside these I just mentioned.

Of course I did some research but couldn't find the correct answer.
Here is somewhat of a duplicate: [jQuery: Count number of list elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605969/jquery-count-number-of-list-elements)

Comment: The question specifically states the asker DOES NOT want the LI nested within any UL other than UL.menu

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `>` child selector:

```
$('ul.menu>li').length
```

Or `.children()`:

```
$('ul.menu').children('li').length
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is my answer. I used the function size but that didnt work out for me. But what is the > arrow for? i haven't seen it being used in CSS? Sorry, here to learn not to copy paste

Comment: @KrijnvanderBurg You’ll find plenty of information in the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors

Comment: > means the direct decendant

Comment: just as an alternative for newer browsers and without the use of jQuery: `document.querySelectorAll('ul.menu > li').length` works the same

Answer (score 2):

The other question is in jQuery, so I answer for jquery, try this to count your `li` elements

```
var count = $('ul.menu').children('li').length;
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vTHe5/1/)

Comment: Why downvote? Explain please... because demo works fine

Comment: Your answer was downvoted before you made your edits (not by me)

Comment: Because OP is not searching for all `li` just the first level. Your answer gives 12 instead of 5.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. This also works, but i am sticking with Davids answer, simply because that is smaller. Thank you very much for helping me!

Comment: Yes David answer is the correct and best answer but I'm glad to help you @KrijnvanderBurg